# Sort a list of dictionary based on values of 'date', and the values are in the format dd-MON-YYYY(example: 15-APR-2021)

Tags: python, list, date, dictionary

I have data of the following type and my code for sorting is as followed by the example data:

```
list = [{ key1:'value',date:'14-APR-2021'}, {key1:'value', date:'15-MAR-2020'},{key1:'value', date:''}]
sorted_list = sorted(list, key = lambda i: i[date]]))
```

with this I am able to get

```
sorted_list = [{key1:'value', date:''},{ key1:'value',date:'14-APR-2021'}, {key1:'value', date:'15-MAR-2020'}]
```

i.e., it is being treated as a string

but the correct answer should be

```
sorted_list = [{key1:'value', date:''}, {key1:'value', date:'15-MAR-2020'}, { key1:'value',date:'14-APR-2021'}]
```

Comment: Does the date format need to stay the way or are you okay with ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)?

Comment: @white Yes, the date format needs to stay. I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71569730/18483231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date-format does not sort lexicographically, that's why you're getting the wrong result. One solution is to sort by the corresponding datetimes instead of the string representation.

```
from datetime import datetime

def to_date(s):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(s, '%d-%b-%Y')
    except ValueError:
        return datetime.min
    
lst = [{'key1':'value', 'date':'14-APR-2021'}, {'key1': 'value', 'date': '15-MAR-2020'},{'key1': 'value', 'date':''}]
result = sorted(lst, key=lambda d: to_date(d['date']))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': 'value', 'date': ''}, {'key1': 'value', 'date': '15-MAR-2020'}, {'key1': 'value', 'date': '14-APR-2021'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

the date is in string format, so when you sort the list it is actually being compared based on the 'ascii' values of string characters

for example: 'a' is smaller/less than 'b' (ascii for 'a' is 97 and for 'b' is 98)

In this code,

`14-APR-2021` with `15-MAR-2020`

('4' < '5') in '14' and '15'

so, '4' is smaller than '5'.

Comment: Yes, I realised that was the problem. I needed a way to convert the string to date.
Thanks for your reply anyways. :)